How to By-Pass sysadmins or DB-owners from RLS policy
I have written RLS policies which will filter the users(impersonated from Tableau) logged in against a USER_ACCOUNT table inside the database, so in short if the logged in user have an entry in USER_ACCOUNT table only then the he\she can see their respective rows.
All good as of now, but there is new requirement for one user to bypass RLS.
When I tried adding condition to bypass db owners from RLS using below option, the dbowner is able to bypass but the other user queries are not just running in loop or not completing.
Script:
CREATE FUNCTION colleague.fn_Security_user_accounts_table(@UserName AS sysname)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN

SELECT 1 AS fn_Security_user_accounts_table -- Logic for filter predicate
WHERE @UserName = USER_NAME()
   or IS_ROLEMEMBER ('db_owner') = 1 


Is that the real code? Looks incorrect to me

"other user queries are not just running in loop or not completing" that is most likely a query plan issue

But when i remove the line IS_ROLEMEMBER, everything is working fast as usual
